# HD audio for Nvidia cards

Tags: audio, computer-building

I have an Nvidia videocard (GTX275) and it has a connector for "HD Audio". Where should I connect this on my board and why should I connect this? What is the benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect that cable to Pins 3 and 5 of your motherboard's S/PDIF header (see diagram below) you can pass audio from the motherboard through the video card's HDMI port. [Here](http://www.evga.com/support/faq/afmmain.aspx?faqid=58021)'s a FAQ entry from eVGA with more information.
[image]

Comment: What will I achieve by passing "audio from the motherboard through the video card's HDMI port"?

Comment: If you have your computer hooked up to a TV or AV Receiver with an HDMI cable both video and audio will be passed through that cable. If you don't connect this header then the HDMI cable will only be carrying video and you will need to hook up an additional cable for audio.